# Django mixin and FormView template confusion with CBV

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms, mixins, django-class-based-views

I'm still a noob at mixins in general so I'm just trying to understand what happens in this code that uses Ajax to submit forms. I've been scouring the docs for a whole day to try to figure out what happens. The code seems to work but I just don't entirely understand why. I still have a lot of question marks on the whole process so if anyone can correct my thinking that would be amazing

1. The AjaxableResponseMixin extends the form_invalid() and form_valid() methods of the FormView to support Ajax requests

   - Why is the Ajax class referring to itself with super()?
   - How does the class know to extend FormView's methods?
2. If the request is not Ajax it returns response

   - What does the response object do/have? Does it show a template? Does it have context for the template?
3. CreatePostView is a child class of the two parent classes that are passed in (AjaxableResponseMixin, FormView)

   - Do the order of the classes in the params have an impact in general and more specifically when calling super()?
   - When CreatePostView calls form_valid() and form_invalid() is it overwriting the Ajax class? If it isn't, what class methods is it changing?
4. If the form is valid then a post gets created and super().form_valid() gets called which then redirects to the success url because thats what the FormView.form_valid() does

   - Again, why is the super() referring to the FormView?
   - Am I better off just doing a HttpResponseRedirect instead of using super().form_valid()
5. If the form is invalid it redirects to the url with the "create_post" name

   - How do I redirect to the create post page and keep the data in the form the user tried to submit?

views.py

```py
class AjaxableResponseMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin to add AJAX support to a form.
    Must be used with an object-based FormView (e.g. CreateView)
    """
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            data = {
                'pk': self.object.pk,
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response


class CreatePostView(AjaxableResponseMixin, FormView):
    form_class = CreatePostForm
    template_name = 'forum/create_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        form.create_post(user_obj=user)
        messages.success(self.request, 'Your post was published')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, 'Your post could not be published. Please try again')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_post'))
```

Thank you so much to anybody who answers.

Comment: This is called multiple inheritance in python and basically your question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your question relates to python multiple inheritance and MRO (method resolution order). Look it up, there are plenty of other resources that explain it in detail. But to help with your specific case, you have defined the inheritance in this order:

```
 CreatePostView --> AjaxableResponseMixin ...> FormView
```

This is the order in which subclassed methods will be called. I've made the arrows different because the first is a subclass - parent class relationship, the second one isn't (`CreatePostView` is a subclass of both `FormView` and `AjaxableResponseMixin`)

I'll explain what happens with `form_valid`: So if you call the `form_valid()` method on a `CreatePostView`, its `form_valid()` method is called. This runs all the code of that method.

The last line of that method is `return super().form_valid(form)` telling python to call the parent's class method. With MRO, that is the `AjaxableResponseMixin.form_valid` method. But the first line is `response = super().form_valid(...)`, which is `FormView.form_valid()`.

So here, because `super()` is at the beginning, you effectively tell python to first go to the next in the MRO chain.

`AjaxableResponseMixin` does nothing with the `super()` response if the request is an ajax request (it returns JSON with the object pk as data), but if it's not an ajax request, it just returns the `FormView` response. In this case it's a redirect to the `success_url`, because that's what `FormView` does in case of success. You can see that [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/).

Now you can do the same exercise with `form_invalid()`. In fact, it should just `return super().form_invalid(form)`. It should never redirect, because you want it to `render` the same form on the same page (in the normal case) or just report the form errors in the ajax case.

Notes:

- If your method does not call `super()`, which is entirely legal, the parent's class method will never be called.
- The order of the classes and the order of the calls is important. With Django CBVs, you will most often **first** call `super()` to take care of the basics (the default behaviour) and then add your own stuff. In your `form_valid`, you do it the other way round because you first want to save the object, otherwise the JSON cannot contain the object's pk. And actually, if used incorrectly, this mixin will crash on that line.
- A mixin like `AjaxableResponseMixin` doesn't contain any python code forcing it to be "mixed" with a `FormView`, but it has to, because it calls `super().form_valid()`. In fact many IDEs warn you with that call. There's no way to tell python that `AjaxableResponseMixin` **MUST** be mixed with a `FormView`, but it should be part of the documentation so other developers know how to use it. The same holds for the warning that the object must be saved **before** calling `AjaxableResponseMixin.form_valid`.